# Can we insert html contents into google docs using google docs api with PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am working on google docs api with PHP code. I want to insert html contents into google docs. Is there any way doing this and if yes, How we can achieve that as I have searched a lot but couldn't found a proper answer or solution to this problem.

Comment: I think that inserting the HTML into Google Document is difficult. But I think that the HTML can be converted to Google Document. In this case, you can achieve this using Drive API. Is this method included in the direction you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike, Thanks for your reply, But can you tell me by this way, can we insert that converted html into google docs in a particular existing google document with its document Id using Google docs Api or Google drive api?

Comment: About `can we insert that converted HTML into google docs in a particular existing google document with its document Id using Google docs Api or Google drive api?`, I think that in the current stage, it is difficult to directly achieve this. For example, when the converted document is simple, it can be achieved. But I think that when the converted document is complicated, it is difficult to achieve your goal. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike, can you tell me how we can convert html into google docs?

Comment: In your situation, where is the HTML data?

Comment: @Tanaike, I am writing my Html contents into a Php file.

Comment: From your replying, I proposed a sample script for uploading an HTML file to Google Drive by converting it to Google Document as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike,Sure I'll check and confirm back to you.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to upload an HTML file to Google Drive by converting it to Google Document using googleapis for PHP.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```php
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client); // Please use your authorization script.

$html_file = "./sample.html"; // Please set the filename with the path of HTML file.
$folder_id = "###"; // Please set the folder ID you want to put.

$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'sample',
    'parents' => [$folder_id ],
    'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
));
$res = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => file_get_contents($html_file),
    'mimeType' => 'text/html',
    'uploadType' => 'multipart',
    'fields' => 'id'
));
$file_id = $res->getId();
print($file_id);
```

- In this script, the HTML file is uploaded to Google Drive, and the HTML data is converted to Google Document.

#### Reference:

- [Upload file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)