# How to upload html to google drive and transform into google docs?

Tags: javascript, google-api

I need to create a google doc but with some html in it. After searching a lot, it looks like it's not possible to just use the google docs api and create a new document with the html, it's not going to convert the text into actual html.

So I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71247859/can-we-insert-html-contents-into-google-docs-using-google-docs-api-with-php) question, which the person says to upload a html file and convert to a google docs. But it's using PHP and I need to do this only using the REST api, but I just can't get this to work.

In my case, the document is actually created, but with no content.

This code creates the google docs file:

```js
    const { body } = await superagent
      .post(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files`)
      .send({
        name: 'Some title',
        mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
        data: '<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>',
      })
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
```

And the part that I don't know what to do is how to upload my html and put into this google doc file.

I'm using `superagent` to send the request, but the answer can be with `fetch`, `axios` or whatever.

And the html content will be a string that I will provide in the frontend, but for now just making it work with `<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>"` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

So actually what I had to do is to call the upload endpoint and send a html file and the metadata using `FormData`, like this:

```js
const file = new Blob(['<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>'], {
      type: 'text/html',
    });
    const metadata = {
      name: note?.title,
      mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document',
    };
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append(
      'metadata',
      new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: 'application/json' }),
    );
    form.append('file', file);
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({ Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }),
        body: form,
      },
    ).then((res) => res.json());
```